# How do I change the default PHP base-version on shell?

Tags: php, centos7, php-7, webmin, virtualmin

I have Centos 7 and Virtualmin installed, with the tipycal php-fpm 5.4, 7.0, 7.1 that you can choice between the versions you prefer on every virtualhost via Virtualmin control panel, and everything works well.

But when I access to the server via SSH and check `php -v` I get this:

`PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 19:30:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies`

How can I select another php default/base version for the shell system?

Answer (score 3):

When you issue the php command on the shell it uses the default php version on the server which in your case is **php-5.4.16**

To use another php version, you have to check where the binaries for those php versions are and invoke them with their full path rather than just typing php.

For example, on **CentOS**, for **PHP 7.2** for example, the full path of the **php binary** is: `/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/bin/php`

```
root@virtualmin /root
» /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.24 (cli) (built: Nov  4 2019 10:23:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Would that be to activate PHP?
In the case of your example PHP 7.2, correct?

If so it is very useful for me !!! Thanks!

Comment: That’s to use from the shell another php version than the default one. For websites you switch php versions from virtualmin web interface

Comment: Good!
So does it default to the entire system?
For example Centos 7 comes standard with php7.2.

Using this command do I make php7.3 the default for the entire system?

Sorry I was confused because in Apache - Centos 7, you can use:

`code`   yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73 `code`

How do I do NGINX?
Do I use your command?

Comment: You can just create an alias for php and point it to the desired php version like: alias php=“/path/to/desired/php-version-binary”

Answer (score 3):

---

## Install versions of PHP in centos 7

---

**Setup Yum Repository**
First of all, you need to enable Remi and EPEL yum repositories on your system. Use the following command to install EPEL repository on your CentOS and Red Hat 7/6 systems

Use this command to install EPEL yum repository on your system

```
 sudo yum install epel-release
```

and now execute one of the following commands as per your operating system version to install the Remi repository.

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

Install PHP 7 on CentOS
Your system is prepared for the PHP installation from yum repositories. Use one of the following commands to install PHP 7.4 or PHP 7.3 or PHP 7.2 or PHP 7.1 on your system based on your requirements.

### Install PHP 7.4

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php74 install php
```

### Install PHP 7.3

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php
```

### Install PHP 7.2

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php
```

.
**Check version PHP install**

```
php -v
```

.

```
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 16:35:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

**Install PHP Modules**
You may also need to install additional PHP modules based on your application requirements. The below command will install some more useful PHP modules.

#### For PHP 7.4

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php74 install php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt
```

#### For PHP 7.3

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt
```

#### For PHP 7.2

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the **default** php version on centos was the question. Placing a `path` or `alias` in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file sets the php version for a specific user not the default to be used.

So in my case the solution where provided in these steps (using CentOs and Plesk):

1. `which php`

`/usr/bin/`

Inside that directory when you do `ls -la` you find the old `php` folder.

2. `mv php php-backup` - create a backup
3. `ln -s /opt/plesk/php/8.2/bin/php php` - creates a new symlink to the desired php version.
4. `php -v`

`PHP 8.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2023 11:40:59) (NTS) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v8.2.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies`

Et voilà. The default php has been set for the system. (when not overwritten by a profile)

Btw, I needed to set the default for the systems php because of running a php command from a supervisor script.

Answer (score -1):

### Update

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up Yum Repository

# Install EPEL repository
sudo yum install -y epel-release

# Enable Remi repository
sudo yum install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

## Install PHP 8.2

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php82 install -y php
```

## Check PHP Version

```
php -v
```

## Install PHP Modules (Adjust this based on your requirements)

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php82 install -y php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt
```